# Вопрос про podman + kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, podman

хочу в kubere запустить контейнер podman.

Yaml который использую

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: podman-selenium-standalone
spec:
  containers:
    - resources:
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      name: selenium
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shm
          mountPath: /dev/shm
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      image: 'quay.io/redhatqe/selenium-standalone:latest'
      ports:
        - containerPort: 4444
  volumes:
    - name: shm
      emptyDir:
        medium: Memory
```

в кубер добавляю, как(в папке с файлом)
-- `kubectl apply -f podman-selenium-standalone.yaml`

В кубере поднимается, но не могу простучаться на порт 4444
Ни сюда(http://172.17.0.5:4444 -- но это вроде как внутренний адрес контейнера, поэтому и не можем простучаться), ни сюда - http://localhost:4444 - тут пишет `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` (примерно сразу обрывает загрузку).

Хотел уточнить что не так настраиваю? Цель - запустить в кубере, podman'ский контейнер.

Comment: Адрес пода 172... - это адрес внутри кластера и к твоей машины прямого отношения не имеет (разве что кластер работает на ней). Это разные сетевые пространства. Команда `kubectl port-forward` в ответе пробрасывает трафик с порта на твоей машине внутрь кластера. Такие вещи при деплое пода через `kubectl apply` не возможны (разве что обернуть в какой-то внешний скрипт или дополнительную команду).

Answer (score 0):

А нашел, там оказывается отдельно еще надо дописать(сделал просто в консоле машины, на которой установлен кубер)

`kubectl port-forward $PODNAME 4444:4444`

И теперь открывается в браузере.

Единственное надо теперь понять, можно ли автоматом это сделать чтобы не прописывать.